# URLSearchParams not working in chrome mobile?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobile-chrome

im making a react web app with the spotify api and the authorization works correctly on both my pc (in brave browser) and my phone on firefox. however, it doesn't work on my phone on chrome. more specifically, im using the code below (in my app.tsx file) to extract the 'code' search parameter from the url and then set the window location to how it is without the code, so when it works i get redirected back to my page and the '?code=...' part is gone. on chrome mobile it stays there and doesn't do anything. anyone know why this is happening? thanks :)
(ps. if you want to take a look at the whole app it's on https://omer-sm.github.io/spotify-playlist-maker)

```
  window.onload = () => {
    //if url has an auth code, get an access token
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
    code = urlParams.get('code')
    if (typeof code === "string" && stage === 0) {
      window.history.pushState({}, document.title, "/spotify-playlist-maker" );
      getToken(code).then(r => {
        setStage(1)
      })
      if (!code) {
        console.log(urlParams.get('error'))
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Did you test this on an actual Chrome on desktop to see if you can replicate it there? Desktop is easier to debug, and it could be interesting to know if its really a mobile issue or just an official Chrome one?

Comment: @somethinghere yeah it works on the desktop chrome